# Add multiple markers with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following function to add one single marker but I want to add multiple markers by clicking on the map. I have Googled but I can't get any straight answer on how I can solve this problem.

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    if(marker) {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: gm_map,
            draggable: true
        });
    }
}
```

I know I need to use `Array()` but I don't know exactly how. How can I solve my problem?

**DEMO**: removed because the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to use the `marker` variable outside of the `placeMarker` function?  Your function is not deleting the marker, it is checking to see if the marker variable exists and moves the marker using the `setPosition` function.  You need to remove that line if you want multiple markers to exist.

```
function placeMarker(location) {
   //marker variable will only exist inside this function
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: location,
       map: gm_map,
       draggable: true
   });        
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/aEyfW/

Comment: Sometimes the hardest problems are the most simplest -.- Many thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you need to have an event listener for the 'click' event on the map.  And this needs to pass the currently-clicked location to your placeMarker function.  Try this (add this event listener in the same place where you initialise your map)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gm_map, 'click', function(event) {
      placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

And modify your placeMarker function, so instead of having one global variable marker which you update with each click, create a new marker each time:

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: gm_map,
            draggable: true
        });
}
```

Comment: Oh drats! I forgot to mention one important detail :( I'm truly sorry for this! I want to add multiple markers using the click function in the API

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But that only set one single marker and if I click once again on the map, the old marker deletes and sets on the new position. Please see what I mean by clicking on the link in my edit (I'll remove the link when this problem has been solved).

Comment: ok, get rid of the global `marker`, just recreate it each time (you might end up with a lot of markers though)

Comment: That's very true :) I haven't think about that. Many thanks! :D